# In python, read lines from input file, print each name, compute average

Tags: python-2.7

I have an input file called 'students' which contains lines like this

```
tim 80 67 80
karl 65 56
nick 40 60 80 54
```

I need to write a Python program that computes the average of all scores for each student and prints two columns (the name, followed by the average).  The name of the file should be read as a command line argument.  Preferably, I would like to use str.strip and/or str.split.

I'm looking for advice about how to go about this more so than actual code (but code could help too).  My thought process is to strip the name from the line and add to the first element of a list, add all scores after the name to elements of a list, than add those scores and divide by the total number of scores for that name (using len?).  Print out name and result from the math and do this until all names have been accounted for...  yet I have no idea how to do this.  Asking on stack was my last option, believe me I have been scouring my sources for days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
file=open(filename,"r")
line = file.readline()
students=[] 
while line != "":
    splitedline=line.split(" ")
    average=0
    for i in range(len(splitedline)-1) :
        print splitedline[i+1]
        average+=int(splitedline[i+1])
    average=average/(len(splitedline)-1)
    students.append([splitedline[0],average])
    line = file.readline()
print(students)
file.close()
```

Work if your file end with 54 and no space after

Comment: Thanks!  This works (also fyi, this works even if the last number is not 54)..
  @La-Loutre I will upvote once I obtain enough rep.